# How to exclude certain URL for lighttpd

Tags: node.js, lighttpd

Ok my main webserver runs with lighttpd, i want to have node.js running as well for certain feature, e.g.

1. http://192.168.1.2       is parsed with lighttpd
2. http://192.168.1.2/path1 is parsed with lighttpd
3. http://192.168.1.2/path2 is parsed with node.js

can you do that ?
if so how to configure it please ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Did you try you question in a search engine?
First result is https://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/3663
With slight modification, and assuming node.js running on localhost on port 3000:

```
$HTTP["url"] = "^/path2" {
    proxy.server  = ("" => (("host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 3000)))
}
```

Comment: Not working yet, btw why do you want to put ^/ before path2 ? i thought ^ means beginning with, but in my case, the URL starts with http://19.168 ...

Comment: In lighttpd, $HTTP["url"] is the URL path, and does not include the URI authority (hostname or IP address)